# Processing the generated CallbackData in aiogram 2.x

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

There is a reference telegram bot. When pressing the  button "°/•Add up discounts" it receives data from the database and forms an inline keyboard based on it, assigning a name and CallbackData to each button. The problem is that the bot does not respond in any way to the clicks of this created keyboard. The code for creating the keyboard:

The code for creating the keyboard:

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
    from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData
    
    from misc.db_comands import get_all_stocks
    
    stocks_cd = CallbackData("show_stocks", "stocks_id")
    
    
    def make_callback_data(stocks_id: int = 0):
        return stocks_cd.new(stocks_id=stocks_id)
    
    
    async def choosing_promotion_keyboards():
        menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        stocks = await get_all_stocks()
        for stock in stocks:
            button_text = f"{stock.name_stock}"
            callback_data = make_callback_data(stock.id)
    
            menu.row(
                InlineKeyboardButton(text=button_text, callback_data=callback_data)
            )
    
        return menu
```

Handler code:

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import CommandStart, Text

from keyboards.inline import choosing_promotion_keyboards, stocks_cd
from keyboards.reply import reply_markup
from misc.db_comands import get_stock


async def get_start(message: types.Message) -> None:
    await message.answer(f"Привет {message.from_user.first_name}!",
                         reply_markup=reply_markup)


async def change_stocks(message: types.Message) -> None:
    menu = await choosing_promotion_keyboards()
    await message.answer("Выбери нужную акцию⬇️", reply_markup=menu)


async def show_promotion(callback: types.CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict) -> None:
    stock_id = int(callback_data.get("stocks_id"))
    stock = await get_stock(stock_id)
    text = F"Вы выбрали {stock.name_stock}"
    await callback.message.edit_text(text)


def register_hendlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(get_start, CommandStart())
    dp.register_message_handler(change_stocks, Text(equals="°/•Сложить скидки"))
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(show_promotion, stocks_cd.filter())
```

I don't understand at all where I'm making a mistake. I ask for help in this matter.